# Saving veins data in a SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, omnet++, veins

Good morning everybody.
I'm using Veins 4.4 and Omnet++ v4.6.

Is it possible to save data collected through a Veins simulation (i.e. WaveShortMessage fields) in my SQLite DB?

thanks in advance
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite support for OMNeT++ 5.1 is a work in progress. There will be a preview release before the holidays so if you can port your code OMNeT++ 5.1 (PRE2) you will be able to configure an SQLite vector manager (instead of the current text based one) which will write out the vector data to a SQLite database. A preliminary version was presented at the 2016 OMNeT++ Summit: https://summit.omnetpp.org/archive/2016/assets/pdf/OMNET-2016-Session_3-03-Presentation.pdf

Comment: just a further question. where I can find this technical preview with the aloha example? I've read about it in the slides

Comment: That version (preview 1) was distributed only on the summit for a limited number people, however I'm just working on preview 2 version which will be available in a week on the omnetpp.org website.

Comment: Preview 2 is available for testing.